# What kernel modules and other setup are needed for using the RPi3 built in Wi-Fi?

Tags: wifi, linux, kernel, pi-3

## Question

I'm trying to get the Wi-Fi working (again) on my model 3. I am not using Raspbian.

Which kernel config settings and loaded modules are needed for the Wi-Fi device to show up in `ifconfig -a`?

Once the device is detected by the kernel, what `wpa_supplicant` settings are needed? For instance, I've found that `wpa_supplicant` needs `-Dnl80211` for the built-in Wi-Fi while my USB based Wi-Fi dongle (RTL8188CUS) needs `-Dwext`.

Anything else I'm missing?

## Bonus Question

How does the Bluetooth section of the wireless chip play into all of this? They're communicating to the SoC via a shared UART, correct?

## Backstory

I am running gentoo on my Raspberry Pi 3, compiling the raspberry pi kernel myself, which was all working well. I had the built-in Wi-Fi working great.

I modified the kernel source ever so slightly to add support for controlling the LEDs in a MagSafe connector (via 1-wire ds2413 module). This broke the built-in Wi-Fi support.

I've tried reverting the changes I made to no avail. This makes me believe there was some other recent change to the RPi linux fork / firmware that I missed.

Comment: you mean `ifconfig -a`. `ipconfig` is a Windows thing :) Easiest way to answer this is to load raspbian (which I know works on the RPi3, that's what I'm using), run `lsmod` and also look at the boot messages. I'd do it for you, but my 3 is currently off and I'm not at home.

Comment: derp. Thanks for the correction. I'll check `dmesg` again.

Comment: I have the same issue, I just tried enabling bluetooth but it still does not want to come up.

Comment: I have raspberrypi-bootloader and firmware-brcm80211.  From what I can tell the firmware files are present in /lib/firmware/brcm for the pi which are /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.bin and 
/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.txt but dmesg does not say anything about it

Comment: What worked for me was to connect to Ethernet for a while and then it should let the WiFi connect.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure where Gentoo sits with Raspberry Pi compatibility, but best of luck!

If you take a look at ArchLinux and, more specifically Debian's documentation on using `aarch64`/`amd64`, you may find some hints.

[Michael Stapelberg](https://people.debian.org/~stapelberg/) has some notes, and there is the [Debian Raspberry Pi 3 Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/RaspberryPi3) that helps explain some of the new architecture, including how to get WiFi working.  The current image comes with WiFi, so you'll have to look at instructions for images prior to the 2018 one.

I know that you're on Gentoo, but I'm curious if you could follow a similar set of instructions, which is to compile this module, and provide a missing `.txt` file ([`/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.txt`](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XZ7BvbtbBT/)).

The steps are [documented here](https://quantum2.xyz/2017/10/27/installing-debian-arm64-on-raspberry-pi-3-with-wifi/) but consist of:

1. Compiling your kernel with the Broadcom drivers
2. Providing the missing `.txt` file: `/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.txt`

   - [This paste](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XZ7BvbtbBT/) is the current version as of June, 2018.
   - This is sourced from Raspbian `firmware-brcm80211*.deb`, so grabbing it from [here](https://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/f/firmware-nonfree/) is a 'better' way of getting the latest version.

You mention that you've had it working previously.  I'm curious if the `.txt` is missing when you re-compile, incompatible, or if you've compared the files generated by your build to the original, working build.

---

As for your question around UART, yes, UART, WiFi and Bluetooth are all tied together.  [This issue](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1402) discusses some of the limitations and user findings.  On my Raspberry Pi that I use GPIO UART, I have disabled Bluetooth and have added `core_freq=250` in `/boot/config.txt`.  You'll want to read [more information and updates](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=107&t=138223) about this, which will point you at the [`.dts`](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.1.y/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/README) and [device tree](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/device-tree.md) documentation.

I'm not entirely sure what you're doing, but [notro's fbtft](https://github.com/notro/fbtft) framebuffer drivers are a great example of a 'module' that was brought into the mainline Raspberry Pi kernel, showing how to build a new module and how things surrounding that work.

Answer (score 0):

On Debian for my Raspberry Pi 3, I just had to `sudo apt install firmware-brcm80211 wireless-tools`, then reboot, and I could then issue `sudo ip link set dev wlan0 up` and `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan`.